# unsigned integer field in django

Tags: django, django-forms, unsigned, django-models

Any idea how to use an **unsigned integer field** in Django? By this I mean a field inside a model with a range from 0 to 4294967295 and stores 32 bit. This definition excludes the `PositiveIntegerField` because it only has a range from 0 to 2147483647. I also prefer not to use a `bigIntegerField` as that would be a huge waste of memory.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, the only unsigned integer fields in Django are `PositiveIntegerField` and `PositiveSmallIntegerField` which are both too small for you. You'll probably have to look at a custom field to get what you want. Documentation for that is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/). One thing that is really helpful when writing custom fields is to look at the code for one of the official django model fields. They can all be found at `django/db/models/fields/__init__.py`

I would post some code but I don't have enough experience with custom fields to be confident that it would be what you need. Good luck!`

Answer (score 4):

Gave it a go in creating a custom `UnsignedIntegerField`. Tested only manually for inserting unsigned 32-bit integers.

```
from django.core import validators
from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class UnsignedIntegerField(models.IntegerField):

    MAX_INT = 4294967295

    @cached_property
    def validators(self):
        # These validators can't be added at field initialization time since
        # they're based on values retrieved from `connection`.
        validators_ = [*self.default_validators, *self._validators]
        min_value, max_value = 0, self.MAX_INT
        if (min_value is not None and not
            any(isinstance(validator, validators.MinValueValidator) and
                validator.limit_value >= min_value for validator in validators_)):
            validators_.append(validators.MinValueValidator(min_value))
        if (max_value is not None and not
            any(isinstance(validator, validators.MaxValueValidator) and
                validator.limit_value <= max_value for validator in validators_)):
            validators_.append(validators.MaxValueValidator(max_value))
        return validators_

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "INTEGER UNSIGNED"

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "UnsignedIntegerField"

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super().formfield(**{
            'min_value': 0,
            'max_value': self.MAX_INT,
            **kwargs,
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 2.2, there is official documentation on how to create custom fields. The best part is, now they have an example of creating `UnsignedAutoField` right [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/). For my use case with Django 2.0, this snippet was sufficient.

```
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField

class UnsignedAutoField(AutoField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'integer UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT'

    def rel_db_type(self, connection):
        return 'integer UNSIGNED'
```

Hope this helps.